# BarcodeScanner Mlkit example - How to get the codebar image as a Bitmap

Tags: bitmap, barcode-scanner, firebase-mlkit

I am using the barcode detection example from the following repository: [MLKit example](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/CameraXLivePreviewActivity.java)

In the CameraXLivePreviewActivity activity, the BarcodeScanner class is used to detect the barcode. How can I get the image where the barcode was detected as a Bitmap and save it on the device.

I have tried to save the image in a global variable inputImage in the method

```
@Override
protected Task<List<Barcode>> detectInImage(InputImage image) {
    inputImage = image;
    return barcodeScanner.process(image);
}
```

of the BarcodeScannerProcessor but when I use that variable in the onSuccess method of the BarcodeScannerProcessor, when I call the following method inputImage.getByteBuffer() on convertImage method to convert to Bitmap, the buffer returned is null

```
@Override   protected void onSuccess(
  @NonNull List<Barcode> barcodes, @NonNull GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay) {
    Bitmap originalImage = convertImage(inputImage);
}
```

And convertImage method:

```
private Bitmap convertImage(InputImage originalImage){

  if (originalImage != null) {
    int width = originalImage.getWidth();
    int height = originalImage.getHeight();

    ByteBuffer buffer = originalImage.getByteBuffer();

    FrameMetadata.Builder builder = new FrameMetadata.Builder();
    builder.setHeight(height);
    builder.setWidth(width);
    builder.setRotation(90);
    FrameMetadata metadata = builder.build();

    return BitmapUtils.getBitmap(buffer, metadata);
  }
  return null;
```

}